# perform 2 or more control events on uibutton in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

My question we can perform 2 or more event on single `UIButton` in swift

Here is my code
here button is one but have 2 different actions
next function gives touch up inside event and
fast-forward function gives touch down event

When I tapped next button then it's works perfectly and called fast-forward function but I release button it's automatically call next function

But I want to when I tapped next button then call only fast forward function and when I click on next button than call only next function

```
 @IBOutlet var next: UIButton!

 @IBAction func next(sender: AnyObject) {


     if sh.enabled == false &&  b <= sha.count - 1
    {
     movieplayer.stop()
     b++
     play.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
     shuffleplaying()
    }
    else if rep.enabled == false
    {
     if a < arr.count - 1
     {
        a++
        play.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        startplaying()
     }
     else
     {
        a = 0
        play.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        startplaying()
     }
    }
    else if a <= arr.count - 1 || play.titleLabel == "Play"
    {
        //movieplayer.stop()

        play.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        a++
        startplaying()

         if a > arr.count - 1
         {
           a = 0
          startplaying()
          movieplayer.pause()
            play.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            flag = 1
        }
    }
}

   @IBAction func fastforward(sender: AnyObject) {
    movieplayer.currentPlaybackRate = 10
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by tap & click?

Comment: Thanks for reply  when i press long on button then only call fast forward action and i click on button then call next action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS SDK includes two gesture recognizers:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer
UILongPressGestureRecognizer
```

Create your button without attaching any actions. Then create two gesture recognizers, one of each type, each mapped to the action you want. Then attach the gesture recognizers to the button.

[image]

Comment: thanks for reply you have any example of GestureRecognizer because i am new in swift

Comment: See the screenshot how i have added gestures to the button. Just drag and drop tap & long press gesture from object library to the button. For long press in the attribute inspector you can change min duration as you want. Then in viewcontroller scene select gesture ctrl + drag to viewcontroller and add action. Hope this helps you.